# Búsqueda Avanzada archivo CSV en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buen día.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, tengo una lista en una archivo CVS como la siguiente.

```
Out[4]:

_usuarios,Estrato_A1,Estrato_A,Estrato_B,Estrato_C,Estrato_D  
1       ,  6.86     ,   5.43  ,     4.30  ,      3.53  ,     2.73   
2      ,  10.97  ,      8.68   ,     6.88 ,       5.65  ,     4.37   
3      ,  15.08     ,  11.93   ,     9.46   ,     7.76  ,     6.00   
4      ,  19.20     ,  15.19    ,   12.04   ,     9.88  ,     7.64   
5      ,  23.15    ,   18.31     ,  14.51   ,    11.91   ,    9.21
```

Donde mi dato de entrada puede ser `_usuarios = 4` y `Estrato = C`, y necesito que me arroje el valor de `9.88`.

Este es otro ejemplo que estaba tratando de ejecutar.

```
import numpy as np

Factor_M = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Factor_M.csv')

Out[27]:

Nro._de_usuarios ,Factor_M
5 , 9.49
6    , 10.80
7    , 12.10
8   ,  13.50
9   ,  14.80


def find_nearest(Factor_M,value):

    idx = (np.abs(Factor_M-value)).argmin()
    return Factor_M[idx]

value = 21

print(find_nearest(Factor_M, value))
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que llevas escrito? Postea el código que llevas. Una ayudita: [https://github.com/euribates/Charla-DSL/blob/master/Ejemplo-uso-pyparsing.ipynb]

Comment: No se si me aclaro, parece como si la explicación y el código buscaran algo diferente "dato de entrada puede ser _usuarios = 4 y Estrato = C, y necesito que me arroje el valor de 9.88" pero el código parce que busca que ingresando 9.88 retorne ser _usuarios = 4 y Estrato = C la columna y fila del valor mas cercano de no existir. ¿Es esto último lo que buscas? Si es así ¿Que debe retornar si encuentra más de un valor iguales o a la misma distancia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer, es almacenar el contenido del archivo CVS en una lista, de tal modo que las filas sean los distintos usuarios, y cada columna de la fila podrían ser los diferentes estratos con su correspondiente identificador en la primera posición.
Más o menos te quedaría algo así:

```
LCVS=[
        [ # La primera fila contiene los datos del primer usuario
            ["A1",(6.86)], # las columnas son listas de dos elementos, el identificador y el valor
            ["A",(5.43)],
            ["B",(4.40)],
            ["C",(3.53)],
            ["D",(2.73)]
        ],
        [
            # Los datos del usuario 2
        ],
        # Y así hasta el último dato
        [
            # Los datos del ultimo usuario
        ]
    ];
```

Luego, cualquier operación, ya sea consulta de datos de un determinado usuario y un estrato, sería más sencilla(?

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Voy a tratar de implementar.